# Matrix Pointers in Java

Tags: java, matrix

What's the best approach os standard mechanism for playing with matrix pointers in Java?

Basicallly I got a matrix and like to work with something like cellPointers
where I can retrieve getXaxisIndex(), getYaxisIndex() and getCellValue().

If only standard arrays stored references like this...:

```
myMatrix[1][3]=235 //Auto or myMatrix[1][3].setValue(235)
myPointer=myMatrix[1][3]
myPointer.getX()=1
myPointer.getY()=3
myPointer.getValue()=235
```

Comment: Legacy code, know-how, many reasons why I cannot assess moving to C for that particular need but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: No standard mechanism as far as I know... Maybe a generic class `Pointer` with methods `getX()`, `getY()`, `getValue()`, `setValue()`, etc? And then you have a matrix of these `Pointer`s? And maybe a `Matrix` class that wraps the actual matrix?

Comment: @user1352530 Never mind, I misread the question originally. As Magnamag points out, you cannot "extend" native types like that. The (only) way to go here is using your own classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might implement is

```
class Cell {
    Cell( int x, int y ){...}
    Cell( int x, int y, int value ){...}
    int getX(){...}
    int getY(){...}
    int getValue(){...}
}

class Table {
    Table( int rows, int cols ){...}
    void put( Cell c ){...}
    Cell get( int x, int y ){...}
}
```

Whether or not Table should contain a Cell[][] depends on some details you haven't mentioned. For a big and sparse array a hash map might be considered.